# Angular ternary operator ? with functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following scenario; I have two functions that are actioned from a button:

`<button ng-click="functionOne || functionTwo()"></button>`

now I want to optimise a bit that and I want to call these functions only when they return something, anything , otherwise I don't want to be called and to return null or something. Now I'm wondering if is possible to use ternary operator having something like:

`<button ng-click="condition ? functionOne || functionTwo() : null"></button>`

calling the functions only when `condition` is true.

I have tested and is not really worked :|

Comment: You can't determine whether a function will return something without actually running it...

Comment: please add what `functionOne` is doing?

Comment: @NinaScholz is looking if there are some notifications and if there are should call the function to clear all notifications.

Comment: is `functionOne` a flag or a function? if function, you need to call it.

Comment: @NinaScholz is a function

Comment: if `functionOne()` is falsy, you want to call `functionTwo()`?

Comment: Put your logic into a function, instead of writing it inline in the `ng-click`.  `ng-click="myClickFunction(condition)"`, and then `myClickFunction(condition) { if (condition)  {..do this} else {..do that..}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the condition as an argument into the function, and then the function will check it. If it's true, it will do something, otherwise, it will do nothing.

Isn't that cleaner?

```
<button ng-click="functionTwo(condition)"></button>
```

and

```
$scope.functionTwo = function (conditon) {
  if (condition) {
    //do what you want...
  }
};
```

I suppose you wanted functionOne to return your condition in your original question. You can alter that as you wish.

Here is an example of what I'm describing:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvBVqE

If you insist on using a ternary operator then you can do this, however I believe it's more complicated:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXzbBJ